# Show Specific Paragraph within a Div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I am trying to show a specific Paragraph when a specific div is clicked upon. I cannot get the jQuery to function the way I would like it to.

I want that if the ".Virus" div is clicked on, it shows the contents "v", if ".screenRepair" div is clicked on then it shows the ".screenInfo" contents

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="outerService">
    <div class="service">
        <div class="virus" style="width: 230px; height: 208px;">
            <center>
                <h3 style="width:200px; text-align:center">Computer Virus</h3>
                <img src="images/Services/virus.jpg" alt="virus" height="140px"/>

            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="information">
            <p class="v">This is information</p>
            <p class="screenInfo">hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="screenRepair" style="width: 230px;">
            <center>
                <h3 style="width:auto; text-align:center">Screen Replacement</h3>
                <img src="images/Services/smashedScreen.jpg" alt="BrokenScreen" height="140px"/>

            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerService {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.service {
    display: table;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1044px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.virus, .screenRepair, .hardwareRepair, .WindowsReinstall, .maintenance, .SoftwareRepair, .MemoryUpgrades, .DataRecovery {
    width: 250px;
    height: 208px;
    float: left;
    max-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}


#vInfo {
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.information {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

    .information p {
        text-align: justify;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".virus").click(function () {
        $(".information .v").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the relation between those divs?

Comment: the .virus and .screenRepair divs are the boxes that can be clicked on, and they should show information in the .information div

Comment: Set the styles for `.v` and `.screenRepair` to `display:none;` and remove `display:none;` from `.information`

Comment: @RandomMath is this you want https://jsfiddle.net/c283uaog/5/

Comment: @NewToJS I want that onclick of one of the DIVS, the .information div shows along with the corresponding text

Comment: @RandomMath if you hide `.information` it will make no difference if elements within that are set to `show()` or `hide()` as the container for those elements is still hidden hence the changes in the css.

Answer (score 0):

With your current CSS you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $info = $( '.information' );
    $(".virus").click(function() {
        $info.show().find( 'p:not(.v)' ).hide().siblings().show();
    });

    $(".screenRepair").click(function() {
        $info.show().find( 'p:not(.screenInfo)' ).hide().siblings().show();
    });
});
```

Or you can slightly change your CSS and try to hide every P within .information instead of hiding .information itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**change information div properties in your css (remove display:none)**

```
 .information {
      margin-left: 10px;
      border:3px solid green;
      margin-top: 230px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      height: 200px;
      max-width: 100%;
 }
```

**and add this lines to your css**

```
 .information .v {
       display:none;
 }

 .screenInfo{
       display: none;
 }
```

Comment: In order to use this solution you should move all the style from .information to every paragraph with it otherwise you'll end up having an empty big box with 200px height and a 3px green border.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".service img").click(function () {
    $(".information .v").toggle($(this).closest('div').hasClass('virus'));
    $(".information .screenInfo").toggle($(this).closest('div').hasClass('screenRepair'));
});
```

---

`.hasClass()` returns boolean `true/false`.

`.toggle(true)` results to show the hidden object while `.toggle(false)` results in hiding the object.

---

As suggested in the comments you need to hide all the infos rather than `.information` div. otherwise you need to show this one before showing any other info div.

---

Some other edits can be done like:

```
.virus, .screenRepair, .hardwareRepair, .WindowsReinstall, .maintenance, .SoftwareRepair, .MemoryUpgrades, .DataRecovery {
    width: 250px;
    height: 208px;
    float: left;
    max-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none; /*<-----add this to hide the info divs.*/
}

.information {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

and then you can add one more line:

```
$(".service img").click(function () {
    $(".information").show(); //<----show it before showing any other div.
    $(".information .v").toggle($(this).closest('div').hasClass('virus'));
    $(".information .screenInfo").toggle($(this).closest('div').hasClass('screenRepair'));
});
```

---

May be you want to look into this:

```
$(".service > div:not(.information)").click(function () {
    $(".information").hide().show(); //<----show it before showing any other div.
    $(".information .v").toggle($(this).hasClass('virus'));
    $(".information .screenInfo").toggle($(this).hasClass('screenRepair'));
});
```

Comment: I am looking for something very similar to that, is there any way to hide the .information div as well and show it and its corresponding contents on the click of one of the box?

Comment: @RandomMath you can use this `$(".information").hide().show();` just hide it before showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Toggle if you want to show and hide div

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#virus').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#information').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

its working here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2jrm08z/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(".virus").click(function() {
                $(".information").show().find('p').show().next('.screenInfo').hide();
            });

             $(".screenRepair").click(function() {
                $(".information").show().find('p').show().prev('.v').hide();
            });
 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtnmb4ga/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".virus").click(function() {
            $(".information").show();
             $(".v").show();
            $(".screenInfo").hide();
        });

         $(".screenRepair").click(function() {
            $(".information").show();
             $(".screenInfo").show();
            $(".v").hide();
        });
```

});

Comment: An explanation what the problem is and why your code solves it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

[see in live](https://jsfiddle.net/awggjnuc/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.virus').click(function() {
                $('.information').show();
                $('.v').show();
            });

        });


.information {display:none;}  .information p{display:none;}
```